# How to prevent background service from crashing in Android

Tags: android, service

I am using the google calendar api to fetch the user data from a background service.

The service runs periodically to fetch the user data from the api and some operation is performed on that data.
Since it is a background service there is no user interaction when I fetch the data after the authorization process.

So what is the correct way of handling the crash that might be caused due to failure of the service.

Comment: I am sure failure of service or some unexpected behavior might lead to generation of exception, which in turn leads to crashing as it was unhandled. I would suggest you read what are exception and errors? how to handle it? and decide how your app should behave in such cases. Now if you are talking of background service not working in latest Android OS (i.e Android 10) then kindly [refer](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) and also [refer](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First analyze the root cause of the crash ,check the log proper . most of the time it may occur because of the null pointer exception.Handle all the null from the service.